# Angular 1.5, $interval and allowing GC to do it's work

Tags: angularjs, garbage-collection, intervals

Long time lurker; first time poster.

My requirement is to poll (via http get) a server continuously and display the responses in the browser. I'm using angular 1.5. I have a logic error that is preventing garbage collection from freeing up memory. I ***think*** I've boiled it down to my (incorrect?) usage of $interval.

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Here's my script.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {

    $scope.counter = 0;

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        $interval(function() {
            theWatcher()
        }, 100);
    });

    var theWatcher = function() {
        $scope.counter++;
    };

}]);
```

Here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <link data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker! {{counter}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[A plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tBaoHy?p=preview)

[Chrome developer tools JS Heap Timeline over 90 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgoRV.png) (Notice how the garbage collection kicks in but it never seems to collect everything; I would have expected a sawtooth pattern over time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$interval` has a static function called `cancel([promise])`. Use it when you want to cleanup ongoing `$interval` instances (it also accepts a single promise).

Working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/emfgkURMmZx4YEEHqXFo?p=preview)

Comment: Muli, thank you very much for your response. 

Based upon your suggestion to cancel the promise, I changed my example code from using $interval to using $timeout. After each timeout, I cancel the previous promise and set it to undefined. Yet my issues still persists. The garbage collection never reclaims what I believe that it should and the javascript heap keeps growing.

New Plunker [https://plnkr.co/edit/NhGdi3Q6djt3iMPHIhd1?p=preview]

Comment: $timeout will only happen once, you don't want that. You want constant-ongoing polls initiated from the client. this is perfect for `$interval`.
I've clarified my answer - check it out.

Comment: Muli, again, I thank you so very much for your response. I have no one here at work that I can ask these questions to.  Your plunkr is very helpful. However it does exhibit the problem of garbage collection not reclaiming all the memory. Over the course of 60 seconds, it leaks 3.9 MB according to the Chrome timeline.  Here is a screen capture of the Chrome timeline on your plunkr: [http://imgur.com/4PjWbRd]. Maybe it is possible that is the best we can do with Angular? Maybe I should consider going with raw javascript for this polling mechanism.

Comment: Your img doesn't work for me. the reason it "leaks" is because the requests pile up in the callstack (you push a function stack containing the `$http` request) every few seconds. If you seek better performance (and by that I mean variable poll rate) I'll post another plunkr.

Comment: Have you switched routes? I had 2 routes set up in there. the moment you move to another route you can see a drop in mem usage.

Comment: My requirements don't allow me to switch routes. I need to continuously poll the server every second and display the results on a single page.  

Sorry about the img failure. [http://imgur.com/gallery/4PjWbRd]

Comment: There's no way around that. You push the callback `function`s onto the stack so you get spikes in memory. Is that a public API you're polling? perhaps I could run some tests.

Comment: Hi Muli. No, it's not a public API. But thank you for the offer. That's very kind of you.    

With my current set of requirements, I don't think I'm going to get much better memory management than you've demonstrated with your plunkr. I really do appreciate all your time looking at this and discussing it with me.  

So I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer. Again, thank you so very much for your time.